# Python Repeat Function/Task Random die roll 6 million Times

Tags: python, repeat

I have no idea what I am doing. I am sorry if this is a silly question. I have tried searching and reading some of the other questions but I really don't understand whats going on.

I don't know if this is supposed to be called a function or task, but basically what I am trying to do is mimic a die being rolled 6 million times. I got it down to where I get a random number, BUT I don't know how to make it repeat this action of getting the random number.... much less 6 million times.

This is all I have. It works for the random integer, but I just need to know how to repeat.

> > > import random
> > >
> > > die_1 = random.randint (1, 6)
> > >
> > > print("The die rolled a:", die_1)

Comment: heard about control flow statements? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `for` control flow statement. Example:

```
from random import randint

for i in range(6000000):
    n = randint(1, 6)
    print('The die rolled a {}'.format(n))
```

For loops: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

String formatting: https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax